# Estimate required sample size in percentage of total market volume to reach representativeness

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sample-size, percentage

Let's assume I have a certain percentage of the total data for all spare parts sold in a country for a specific type of product (for boats or cars etc...).

I want to calculate whether I have enough information about the whole market to make meaningful statements about that market.

**Edit**

Thank you for your answers. I am actually unsure how to clarify my question, but I will try:

Let's start with the example given by BruceET below, i.e., the percentage of replacement headlights for Ford trucks. As the data I have is different from that type of problem, but in specific we can modify that example to be
that I have a certain percentage, $X$ of total data about all car spare parts (i.e., Ford + Audi + ...)  in a certain Country. The total market is then (*Sic*, cost of) $T=$ parts$_{\text{Ford}}+$ parts$_{\text{Audi}}+\dots$.

This includes prices and information about which part were sold (e.g., headlights, motorparts....). Now, I want to estimate my `representativeness` (which I guess is hard to quantify), and the `margin of error` for predictions I make for the unknown part $T-X$ of the market.

What I do not have or do not want to consider are total numbers, I just know that I have a certain percentage of the total market data and I want to start from that value.

**Edit2**

Let me start differently. My goal is to judge, if my sample base is significant enough to make any predictions about the total market. Let us start with a much more simple approach. In my case i am not dealing with cars, but with a very specific type of electronic spare parts.

Lets assume for now, that i only have the following information:

- The Total Marketvolume in the spare part market in one Country in Dollar (*Sic*, toal revenue) $M_{total}$
- The number $N$ of spare part vendors per Region $R$ : $N_{R}$
- The total sales volume of all these Vendors $M_{vendors}$ but not the individual volumes.
- as a Result i can calculate the "market share" by $p=(100/M_{total})*M_{vendors}$

What i also have is information about the ammount of parts sold for a specific group $X_{parts,vendors}$ from my subset of $N_{R}$ Vendors. For example, i do know that from these vendors `1000 x Synchronous motor TYP XYZ` were sold. I do want to extrapolate the total number $X_{parts,total}$ of `Synchronous motor TYP XYZ` sold in the total market based on my kowledge of the market share of the subset of $N_{R}$ Vendors.

I am as a first step looking for a save and sound way to judge if my sample size is enough to make such predictions and to get a meassure of how accurate my predicton is. An if it is not enough i would like to now what type of data i need in addtion to make such judgement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe this: Suppose you seek the proportion $p$ of replacement headlights for Ford trucks sold in the UK and you have count $x$ sold in UK out of all $n$ sold everywhere in a particular month, then the estimate of $p$ sold in UK is $\hat p = x/n$ and a 95% confidence interval for  $p$ is $\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}},$ where the 'margin of error' is $E=1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}}.$ Notice that $E$ is a function of $n,$ so you can adjust the period of info collection to make $n$ large enough to get $E$ small enough to be useful. At maximum $E = 1.96\sqrt{1/4n}.$

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I tried to edit my question.

Comment: Percentage without counts or some other way to judge variability will be useless. If you have a stable population of approximately normally distributed dollars/pounds/euros or percentages $X_i$ over $n > 30$ (Independent) months with mean $\bar X$ and standard deviation $S,$ then an approximate 95% CI for $n,$ is $\bar X \pm 2\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}},$ where margin of error is $E =2\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}.$ If you know or can estimate $S,$ you can see what $n$ gives useful $E.$ [Past bedtime now. Will look here later.]

Comment: @BruceET: thank you for your reply! I figured, that i would need to rephrase my question a little. While i have some of the information you hint at in your answer, i think that i need to solve a different question first. Any help would be realy appreciated.